# Multiple array intersection in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection

How to write in javascript(w/wth JQuery) to find values that intersect between arrays?

It should be like

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [2,4,5]
var c = [2,3,6]
```

and the intersect function should returns array with value {2}. If possible it could applicable for any number of arrays.

Thanks

Comment: javascript syntax would be var a = [1,2,3]

Comment: First arrays ar like this `[1, 2, 3]` not like `{1, 2, 3}`, the later are objects.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We'd be happy to help you resolve any problems you run into on your journey to figure out this algorithm, but this site isn't really designed for doing complete problems from start to finish for other people

Comment: Thanks. i had corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

Since you are using jQuery I will suggest use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function  to filter the value that are present in all three array.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = [2, 4, 5]
var c = [2, 3, 6]

var result = $.grep(a, function(value, index) {
  return b.indexOf(value) > -1 && c.indexOf(value) > -1;
})
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Explanation: Loop over any array and filter out the values that are present in other array.

**Update** (for multimidensional array):

Concept - flatten the multidimensional array that is transform [[1,2],3,4] to [1,2,3,4] and then use the same logic used for single dimensional array.

Example:

```js
 var a = [
   [1, 4], 2, 3
 ]
 var b = [2, 4, 5]
 var c = [2, 3, 6, [4, 7]]

 //flatten the array's

 //[1,4,2,3]
 var aFlattened = $.map(a, function(n) {
   return n;
 })

 //[2,4,5]
 var bFlattened = $.map(b, function(n) {
   return n;
 })

 //[2,3,6,4,7]
 var cFlattened = $.map(c, function(n) {
   return n;
 })

 var result = $.grep(aFlattened, function(value) {
   return (bFlattened.indexOf(value) > -1 && cFlattened.indexOf(value) > -1);
 });

 console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this applicable for multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @Memoc : Could you please post an example of what you are looking for. We can extend this to function for multidimensional array too.

Comment: Let say for case like, 
var a = [[1,4], 2, 3]
var b = [2, 4, 5]
var c = [2, 3, 6,[4,7]]

.In this case the num 4 is also intersect between arrays but hence above code couldn't be used for this cases

Comment: @Memoc updated the answer, flatten the array and then move forward with comparision :)

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Can this be used for string or other type of array as well?

Comment: I am having error when trying your solution,
menu.js?compile=false:778 Uncaught TypeError: aFlattened.indexOf is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
// First this is how you declare an array
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,4,5];
var c = [2,3,6];


// Second, this function should handle undetermined number of parameters (so arguments should be used)
function intersect(){
  var args = arguments;
  // if no array is passed then return empty array
  if(args.length == 0) return [];
  
  // for optimisation lets find the smallest array
  var imin = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
    if(args[i].length < args[imin].length) imin = i;
  var smallest = Array.prototype.splice.call(args, imin, 1)[0];
  
  return smallest.reduce(function(a, e){
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
      if(args[i].indexOf(e) == -1) return a;
    a.push(e);
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(intersect(a, b, c));
```

Comment: Does this applicable for multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @Memoc This function should only take one deimensional array. You can give it as many arrays as you want but they all have to be One Dimensonal arrays like the one in the example.

Comment: I tried your solution but hitting error as below. Do I miss any steps?

Uncaught TypeError: smallest.reduce is not a function
    at intersect (menu.js?compile=false:671)

Comment: @Memoc are you sure you are passing **arrays**. Any thing else will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all '**{}**' means Object in JavaScript.
Here is my suggestion.(this is another way of doing it)

```
// declarations  
var a = [1,2,3];  
var b = [2,4,5];  
var c = [2,3,6];  

// filter property of array
a.filter(function(val) {
    if (b.indexOf(val) > -1  && c.indexOf(val) > -1)
        return val;
});
```

what it does is it checks for each element in array 'a' and checks if that value is present in array 'b' and array 'c'. If it is true it returns the value. Simple!!!. The above code should work for String as well but it wouldn't work for IE < 9, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Intersecting 2 ordered lists of length n and m is O(n+m)
// This can be sped up by skipping elements
// The stepsize is determined by the ratio of lengths of the lists
// The skipped elements need to be checked after skipping some elements:
// In the case of step size 2 : Check the previous element
// In case step size>2 : Binary search the previously skipped range
// This results in the best case complexity of O(n+n), if n<m
// or the more propable complexity of O(n+n+n*log2(m/n)), if n<m
function binarySearch(array, value, start = 0, end = array.length) {
    var j = start,
        length = end;
    while (j < length) {
        var i = (length + j - 1) >> 1; // move the pointer to
        if (value > array[i])
            j = i + 1;
        else if (value < array[i])
            length = i;
        else
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
function intersect2OrderedSets(a, b) {
    var j = 0;
    var k = 0;
    var ratio = ~~(b.length / a.length) - 1 || 1;
    var result = [];
    var index;
    switch (ratio) {
        case 1:
            while (j < a.length) {
                if (a[j] === b[k]) {
                    result.push(a[j]);
                    j++;
                    k++;
                } else if (a[j] < b[k]) {
                    while (a[j] < b[k]) j++;
                } else {
                    while (b[k] < a[j]) k++;
                    if (k >= b.length) break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            while (j < a.length) {
                if (a[j] === b[k]) {
                    result.push(a[j]);
                    j++;
                    k++;
                } else if (a[j] < b[k]) {
                    while (a[j] < b[k]) j++;
                } else {
                    while (b[k] < a[j]) k += 2;
                    if (k - 1 >= b.length) break;
                    if (a[j] <= b[k - 1]) k--;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            while (j < a.length) {
                if (a[j] === b[k]) {
                    result.push(a[j]);
                    j++;
                    k++;
                } else if (a[j] < b[k]) {
                    while (a[j] < b[k]) j++;
                } else {
                    while (b[k] < a[j]) k += ratio;
                    index = binarySearch(b, a[j], k - ratio + 1, k + 1 < b.length ? k + 1 : b.length - 1);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        result.push(a[j]);
                        j++;
                        k = index + 1;
                    } else {
                        j++;
                        k = k - ratio + 1;
                    }
                    if (k >= b.length) break;
                }
            }
    }
    return result;
}

function intersectOrderedSets() {
    var shortest = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if (arguments[i].length < arguments[shortest].length) shortest = i;
    var result = arguments[shortest];
    for (var i = 0, a, b, j, k, ratio, index; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (result.length === 0) return result;
        if (i === shortest) continue;
        a = result;
        b = arguments[i];
        result = intersect2OrderedSets(a, b);
    }
    return result;
}
```

How to use:

```
intersectOrderedSets(a,b,c);
```