# Finding intersection in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, intersection

I am trying to find the intersecting values in multiple arrays, that are within an object as follows:

```
object = {
  filterA: ["1","2","3","4"],
  filterB: ["2","5","6","7"],
  filterN: ["2","4","7"]
}
```

The object can hold multiple arrays and the name of the keys can vary. In the described object I need only "2" to be returned.

I have tried to build on this answer: [Multiple array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971051/multiple-array-intersection-in-javascript) but I could not figure it out, as it uses static variables (a,b,c) for the example. If there is a way to do that with lodash, it will be appreciated, but vanilla javascript in ES 5 will do as well!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971051/multiple-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could get the values and take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter with [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

```js
var object = { filterA: ["1", "2", "3", "4"], filterB: ["2", "5", "6", "7"], filterN: ["2", "4", "7"] },
    result = Object
        .values(object)
        .reduce((a, b) => b.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(a)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great use of the filter's `this`.

Comment: I endet up using this solution, after checking the values of the lodash solution, which was initially ok but after a while produced wrong values for some reason. I transpiled the answer with online babel (https://babeljs.io/repl), because the system that I use don't transpile es6.

Comment: Additionally you could sort input arrays by ascending length... since their intersection resides obviuosly  in the shortest one... to speed up a bit the performance !

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple one-liner approach:

```
const res = Object.values(object).reduce((a, b) => a.filter(i => b.includes(i)))
```

But since you want it in ES5 (ECMAScript 2009) version, that means no arrow functions, no includes(), and no usage of Set objects.

```
const res = Object.values(object).reduce(function (a, b) { 
  return a.filter(function(i) {
    //return b.includes(i);
    return b.indexOf(i) >= 0;
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi @wentjun, can you give me an ES5 solution (no arrow functions)

Comment: `includes` is probably not available in ES5 environment without polyfill

Comment: Oh right! Thanks @charlietfl, i have replaced includes with indexOf() >= 0 to check if the element exists in the array.

Comment: @PresianNedyalkov Alright I have edited it one more time

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over first property value(array) and filter out by comparing with remaining property value.

```
// get property values(arraya as array)
let arr = Object.values(object);


let res = arr[0]
  // iterate over first array
  // check value present in remaining object values(arrays)
  .filter(v => arr.slice(1).every(a => a.includes(v)));
```

```js
let object = {
  filterA: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  filterB: ["2", "5", "6", "7"],
  filterN: ["2", "4", "7"]
};


let arr = Object.values(object);

let res = arr[0].filter(v => arr.slice(1).every(a => a.includes(v)));


console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi @Pranav can you give me a ES5 version, without the arrow functions

Comment: @PresianNedyalkov : sure

Comment: @PresianNedyalkov  `arr[0]
      .filter(function(v){ return  arr.slice(1).every(function(a){ return  a.includes(v)}) });`

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` will do the work for you. Check out my code below.

```js
var object = {
  filterA: ["1","2","3","4"],
  filterB: ["2","5","6","7"],
  filterN: ["2","4","7"]
}

var res = Object.values(object).reduce(function (acc, array) {
  return _.intersection(acc, array)
})

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object = {
  filterA: ["1","2","3","4"],
  filterB: ["2","5","6","7"],
  filterN: ["2","4","7"]
}

let arr = Object.values(object);

let res = arr[0].filter(v => arr.slice(1).every(a => a.includes(v)));


console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi @umer, can you give me an ES5 solution (no arrow functions)

Comment: try this: arr[0] .filter(function(v){ return arr.slice(1).every(function(a){ return a.includes(v)}) });

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's [`_.intersection()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersection) can handle multiple arrays. You can create a function with [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) that gets an array of arrays from the object with [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#values), and computes the intersection by using `_.intersection()` with [`_.spread()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#spread).

```js
const { flow, values, spread, intersection } = _

const fn = flow(
  values, // get the arrays
  spread(_.intersection) // spread into intersection
)

const object = {
  filterA: ["1","2","3","4"],
  filterB: ["2","5","6","7"],
  filterN: ["2","4","7"]
}

const result = fn(object)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayOfComparisonArrays = [[1,2,3,4,5], [5,3], [1,3,4,5], [5,1,3]]
let intersectionArray

intersectionArray = arrayOfComparisonArrays.reduce((lastArray, nextArray)=>{
    let intersection = lastArray.filter(x => nextArray.includes(x))
    return intersection
})

//intersectionArray: [ 3, 5 ]
```